# Using coclass that implements multiple interfaces

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I am writing a C++/CLI application that makes use of a COM dll that provides a number of classes.  Most of them implement a number of interfaces.  I was wondering how I can access the methods of each of the various interfaces.  For instance when I look at the type library one of the classes is defined as:

```
coclass FWFile {
    [default] interface IFWFile;
    interface _IFWFileInternal;
    [default, source] interface _FWFileEvents;
    interface CStatistics;
    interface IFWFile2;
    interface IFWFile3;
    interface IFWFile4;
};
```

When I create an object of this type it appears to implement the IFWFile interface.  However, I want to make use of the methods in IFWFile2.  Can I simply create an object of type IFWFile2 and cast it?

```
IFWFile2 file2 = (IFWFile2)file1;
```

Comment: Long answer: yes.  Use C++/CLI syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When using `CoCreateInstance()` you can specify which interface to retrieve from the newly created object. If you want more than one interface - retrieve one when calling `CoCreateInstance()` and use `QueryInterface()` to retrieve the other interfaces. Don't forget to have `Release()` called for each successful interface retrieval.

Just don't C-style cast COM pointers - interfaces are not guaranteed to be in the order specified in the type library *and* the actual class is not guaranteed to actually have the interface implemented. Always use `QueryInterface()` to retrieve interface pointers from COM objects.

Comment: C-casting is even worse than you say - each interface can be implemented with an _entirely different object_. You might even get different pointers back for multiple invocations of `QueryInterface` for the same interface. The only requirement is querying for `IUnknown` always returns the same pointer.